# How to go thought multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array in php and I need when user is on `www.web.com/index?page=graphicdesigner` I read parameter **page** from **get** by `$_GET["page"`]. I need go throught this array and return array under the current position.

So If I am on url above I will get return `echo $array["urlanchor"];` => **graphic-designer**

```
 $jobs = array(
    "graphicdesigner" => array(
        "urlanchor" => "graphic-designer",
        "og:title" => "graphicdesigner ogtitle",
        "og:description" => "graphicdesigner ogdescription",
        "og:image" => "",
        "og:url" => ""
    ),
    "uidesigner" => array(
        "urlanchor" => "ui-designer",
        "og:title" => "uidesigner ogtitle",
        "og:description" => "uidesigner ogdescription",
        "og:image" => "",
        "og:url" => ""
    )
);
```

How it is possible? I can get the correct php code which will be working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query param as the key to select the array from the multidimensional array:

```
 $jobs = array(
    "graphicdesigner" => array(
        "urlanchor" => "graphic-designer",
        "og:title" => "graphicdesigner ogtitle",
        "og:description" => "graphicdesigner ogdescription",
        "og:image" => "",
        "og:url" => ""
    ),
    "uidesigner" => array(
        "urlanchor" => "ui-designer",
        "og:title" => "uidesigner ogtitle",
        "og:description" => "uidesigner ogdescription",
        "og:image" => "",
        "og:url" => ""
    )
);

$page = $_GET["page"];
$pageArr = $jobs[$page];
echo $pageArr['urlanchor'];
```

Comment: It is not working. I get an error `Notice: Undefined index: ui-designer`.

Comment: @MartinJinda your query param is wrong, you are sending `www.web.com/index?page=ui-designer` instead of `www.web.com/index?page=uidesigner`

Answer (score 0):

if you have got `$jobs`.

```
 $jobs = array(
    "graphicdesigner" => array(
        "urlanchor" => "graphic-designer",
        "og:title" => "graphicdesigner ogtitle",
        "og:description" => "graphicdesigner ogdescription",
        "og:image" => "",
        "og:url" => ""
    ),
    "uidesigner" => array(
        "urlanchor" => "ui-designer",
        "og:title" => "uidesigner ogtitle",
        "og:description" => "uidesigner ogdescription",
        "og:image" => "",
        "og:url" => ""
    )
);
```

you should use  `echo $job['graphicdesigner']['urlanchor'] ;` to get the output.